# Use PowerShell to add a user to a group via the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append `| add-adgroupmember` on the end of a `get-aduser` command. The most common error is

```
either because the command does not take pipeline input ....
```

which I find hard to believe. I would rather believe my syntax is at fault.

```
get-aduser -searchbase 'ou=users,dc=domian,dc=domain' -filter {(name -eq "Last, First")} | add-adgroupmember 'group_name'
```

Ideas?

I tested the `get-aduser` by prepending a `$user =` and eliminating the pipeline, the correct user is returned.

Comment: See Get-Help Add-ADGroupMember - it does take pipeline input, but it's expecting the group identity, not the member list from the pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx) you cannot use Add-ADGroupMember with the pipeline. However you can use `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` which is documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617203.aspx).

So assuming that your code is correct, you can do:

```
get-aduser -searchbase 'ou=users,dc=domian,dc=domain' -filter {(name -eq "Last, First")} | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf group_name
```

Answer (score 1):

When I need to add multiple users into a group I just use a `ForEach` loop.

```
Get-ADUser -searchbase 'ou=users,dc=domian,dc=domain' -filter {(name -eq "Last, First")} | ForEach-Object{
    Add-adgroupmember -identity 'group_name' -members $_.SamAccountName
}
```